# Elasticsearch filter by comparing arrays

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to build a permission based filtering system for Elasticsearch queries. Basically each document has a field with an array of permissions required to access the document.
When querying, an array of permissions assigned to the current user is passed, and based on this array I want to filter the results.

For example for the documents:

```
{
  "id: 3,
  "permissions": [access_image, access_metadata]
},
{
  "id: 5,
  "permissions": [access_blob, access_metadata]
},
{
  "id: 7,
  "permissions": [access_image, access_tags]
}
```

And the given permissions

```
["access_image", "access_metadata", "access_blob"]
```

I need a query which only returns the document with id 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to build the filter using a painless script

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/foo/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
"query": {
    "bool" : {
        "filter" : {
            "script" : {
                "script" : {
                    "source": "params.permissions.containsAll(doc['permissions'])",
                    "lang": "painless",
                    "params": {
                        "permissions": ["access_images", "access_metadata"]
                    }
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
'
```